# pandas read_csv usecols and names out of sync

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When trying to read some columns using their indices from a tabular file with pandas `read_csv` it seems the `usecols` and `names` get out of sync with each other.

For example, having the file `test.csv`:

```
FOO A   -46450.494736   0.0728830817231
FOO A   -46339.7126846  0.0695018062805
FOO A   -46322.4942905  0.0866205763556
FOO B   -46473.3117983  0.0481618121947
FOO B   -46537.6827055  0.0436893868921
FOO B   -46467.2102205  0.0485001911304
BAR C   -33424.1224914  6.7981041851
BAR C   -33461.4101485  7.40607068177
BAR C   -33404.6396495  4.72117502707
```

and trying to read 3 columns by index without preserving the original order:

```
cols = [1, 2, 0]
names = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

df = pd.read_csv(
                'test.csv', sep='\t',
                header=None,
                index_col=None,
                usecols=cols, names=names)
```

I'm getting the following dataframe:

```
     X  Y             Z
0  FOO  A -46450.494736
1  FOO  A -46339.712685
2  FOO  A -46322.494290
3  FOO  B -46473.311798
4  FOO  B -46537.682706
5  FOO  B -46467.210220
6  BAR  C -33424.122491
7  BAR  C -33461.410148
8  BAR  C -33404.639650
```

whereas I would expect column `Z` to have the `FOO` and `BAR`, like this:

```
     Z  X             Y
0  FOO  A -46450.494736
1  FOO  A -46339.712685
2  FOO  A -46322.494290
3  FOO  B -46473.311798
4  FOO  B -46537.682706
5  FOO  B -46467.210220
6  BAR  C -33424.122491
7  BAR  C -33461.410148
8  BAR  C -33404.639650
```

I know pandas stores the dataframes as dictionary so the order of the columns may be different from the requested with usecols, but the problem here is that **using usecols with indices and names doesn't make sense**.

I really need to read the columns by their indices and then assign names to them. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation could be clearer on this (feel free to make an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas), or even better submit a pull request!) but `usecols` is set-like - it does not define an order of columns, it simply is tested against for membership.

```
from io import StringIO

pd.read_csv(StringIO("""a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6"""), usecols=[0, 1, 2])

Out[31]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

pd.read_csv(StringIO("""a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6"""), usecols=[2, 1, 0])

Out[32]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

`names` on the other hand is ordered.  So in this case, the answer is to specify the names in the order you want them.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. The docs could be clearer at this point. the solution I found was to not use `names` while reading the file, reorder the df with the same `cols` indices and rename the columns in the end. Something like: `df = pd.read_csv(..., usecols=cols)[cols]; df.columns = names`